# Constraint Layout height takes available space

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a constraint layout and inside a linear layout that looks like a bar that is constrained to the bottom. Besides I have an item (called SwipeFlingAdapterView) that I would like to take the remaining space, meaning to start from the top, and to go all the way down until the top of the linear layout bar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.SwipeFragment">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/likeDislikeBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/like_dislike_height"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/dislikeButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/like_dislike_button_height"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/dislike"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/likeButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/like_dislike_button_height"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/like"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.lorentzos.flingswipe.SwipeFlingAdapterView
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/likeDislikeBar"
        app:rotation_degrees="15.5"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The views are constrained correctly, so theoretically if I remove the height="match_parent" from the SwipeFlingAdapterView, it will take the available space. Setting its height to "match_parent" will cause it to overlay the likeDislikeBar.

Is there a simple way to achieve this? Can I do it with a constraint layout?

Answer (score 3):

It is not recommended to use `match_parent` for any child of the ConstraintLayout as stated in the official [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout.html) and [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout). This applies to both vertical and horizontal dimensions.

In order to make the `SwipeFlingAdapterView` use all available height between the constraints you need to set its `android:layout_height` to `0dp` (to match constraints).

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove

```
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

Also `ConstraintLayout` seems like an overkill for such a simple layout.

`RelativeLayout` is pretty sufficient here. You can set `likeDislikeBar` to have `layout_alignParentBottom` and `SwipeFlingAdapterView` to have `layout_alignParentTop` and `android:layout_above="@id/likeDislikeBar"` in this case.